# Thank you letter!

Tags: discussion

I am quite aware that meta has not designed for what I am about to write, but I cannot help myself. This concerns a recent "question" on MO: [US editors and reviewers vs Iranian Authors?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140738/us-editors-and-reviewers-vs-iranian-authors) Indeed, it wasn't a question at all and it wasn't suitable for MO at all. **But, MO tolerated with the post and upon that let many of his viewers be aware of a phenomenon not familiar to them.** As far as mathematicians concern, the situation described in the post is very complex and may vary from person to person, department to department, university to university and journal to journal. That was why I refrained from comment unless I had the feeling that something was misunderstood or I was directly addressed. Moreover, the post wasn't MO at all and to respect MO I tried to avoid going into lengthy discussion in my comments. But here, I would like to thank MO for its tolerance. However, it does not mean that I am also expecting that MO tolerates this post on meta :)

Comment: This is fairly standard: e.g. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63221/ What is deplorable is that nobody edited the (now deleted) [migrated question on academia.se](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/us-editors-and-reviewers-vs-iranian-authors) where the question would be on-topic, if it were a question at all...

Comment: Important update: the question is alive and well and revised at academia - http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12369/elsevier-actions-following-us-sanctions-on-iran